# Can one choose the streaming resolution of your video on Vimeo as a Plus or PRO member?

Tags: vimeo

I want to share an HD video with a friend I would like to make sure the video is streamed at no less than 720p, and, perhaps, set a custom volume for him as well. Can I do this with a Plus or PRO account on Vimeo.com? Is it worth upgrading for me?

Comment: It seems that this option is not available, as [_this Youtube video report_](https://youtu.be/FNOa65a6N9A?t=4m25s) on the Vimeo PRO experience, from October 2013, suggests there is no such option in the Player Preferences of the Vimeo video settings.